# iOS framework for manipulating sound file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, core-audio, audio-recording

I want to convert a recorded sound file to another data format or a graph which can be comparable/manipulatable with another file of same data format. May be some type of Fourier transform . Does iOS provide some frame work for the same ? I know the core audio framework, AudioToolbox framework, i dont think these two frameworks will help my need. So does any one know how to do that.

Comment: What are your problems with Core Audio and AudioToolbox?

Comment: I have gone through both of the frameworks but i didnt find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting point maybe [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioFormatServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007286).

That said, it will not be wrong to go through [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) too, which has FFT stuff.